# How to select some column on many dataframes

Tags: r, select, iteration

I'm trying to select some column of many dataframes(25)
`data_names` is a list of my data frames

```
for (i in 1 : nb_files) {
    data_names[i] <- select(data_names[i], "HEURE":"NOTE")
}
```

> Error in select.list(test[i], "HEURE":"NOTE"): select.list() cannot be used non-interactively

```
Traceback:

1. select(test[i], "HEURE":"NOTE")
2. select.list(test[i], "HEURE":"NOTE")
3. stop("select.list() cannot be used non-interactively")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'data_names' is a `character` vector specifying the object names.  We need to get the values of the 'data_names' to do the `select`ion.  One option is to get the values in a `list` (`mget`) and then apply the `select`

```
library(tidyverse)
map(mget(data_names), ~  .x %>%
                            select(HEURE:NOTE))
```

As a reproducible example, using the built-in dataset 'mtcars'

```
data(mtcars)
map(mget(c("mtcars", "mtcars")), ~ .x %>%
                                  select(mpg:drat))
```

Comment: Wow it's perfect, and so simple. I was lost. Thank you so much for your help !

Comment: Just one thing, when I do that my dataframe change class for list                                       
 for (i in 1 : nb_files) {
        assign(data_names[[i]],
        map(mget(as.character(data_names[i])), ~  .x %>%
                            select(HEURE:NOTE))
)}

Comment: @Otilrak  The `map` returns a `list` of `data.frames`.  Here, we are simply looping through the `list` of data.frames and subsetting the columns.  So, it shouldn't change the class.  Also, you seem to be updatng the dataset in the global env.  In that case, use `list2env`. i.e. out <- map(mget(....; list2env(out, envir = .GlobalEnv)`, but I wouldn't recommend to update global objects as this should be better kept it in a list

Comment: @Otilrak  Here, the 'data_names' is the object names of the data.frames.  Isn't this the same case in your new question

Comment: Exactly it's the same

Comment: @Otilrak  Then, it should work, because we are getting the values with `mget`